# addClass() doesn't work when a class already set

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the followng jQuery code:

```
$("button#delete").click(function () {
    $("button.btn btn-danger").addClass("disabled");
    $("button.btn btn-default").addClass("disabled");
});
```

My question is why the code above doesn't work and how can I fix it?

Comment: wrong selector i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("button.btn.btn-danger").addClass("disabled"); 
             ^
```

element `button` with class `btn` and `btn-danger`

[**.** class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

---

```
$("button.btn.btn-default,button.btn.btn-danger").addClass("disabled");
                         ^
```

[multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)